# rxjava 2.0 what is the difference between Observable.subscribe and Observable.subscribeActual?

Tags: rx-java2

The documentation just says

protected abstract void `subscribeActual(Observer<? super T> observer)`
Operator implementations (both source and intermediate) should implement this method that performs the necessary business logic.
There is no need to call any of the plugin hooks on the current `Observable` instance or the `Subscriber`.

Answer (score 3):

`Observable.subscribe` comes from the base interface definition in `ObservableSource` and is the main subscription method for `Observable`s: internal and external components use it to run a flow in a standard way.

However, certain actions may be necessary for all kinds of `Observable`s to be executed before the operator's business logic gains access to the incoming `Observer`, for example, applying plugin hooks and protecting against crashing subscribe implementations. So instead of requiring every operator to duplicate this preparation logic, they are in a single place and a new abstract method is present to deal with the customization of an `Observable`.

Comment: I'm sure this answer is correct but it is not very helpful to me. Can you maybe give an illustrative example that distinguishes between subscribe and subscribeActual?

Comment: What is that don't you understand? subscribe() calls the protected subscribeActual() after some preparations, for example, https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/2.x/src/main/java/io/reactivex/Maybe.java#L3722

Comment: Thanks, I looked at the Maybe example, which prompted new questions: Why is Maybe declared abstract? In the docs it is not abstract. And subscribeActual() is also abstract.

Comment: Abstract methods need an abstract class.

Comment: Wouldn't that mean that you can't directly instantiate Maybe? As I noted, it is not shown as abstract in the javadoc

Comment: The [javadoc](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Maybe.html) clearly lists it as abstract. It uses the object-oriented programming principles of requiring an implementation to specify [subscribeActual](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/2.x/src/main/java/io/reactivex/internal/operators/maybe/MaybeMap.java#L39).

Comment: Ah, I see. The headline at the top of the javadoc page just says "Class Maybe<T>"; "abstract" isn't mentioned until farther down the page. My bad. And now I see that apparently all the v.2 sources like Observable, Completable etc. are abstract. This is a major change from RxJava 1 and caught me off guard. Is there some overarching reason for this?

Comment: There is a [design document](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/2.x/DESIGN.md#creation) which outlines some of the changes. (Note it was written more than a year ago before the release candidates cleaned up naming.)