# Trying to understand subscribeActual()

Tags: java, rx-java2

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44714124/rxjava-2-0-what-is-the-difference-between-observable-subscribe-and-observable-su) asks what I want to know, but the answer doesn't explain it. Could someone share a concrete example that illustrates how to use `subscribeActual()` vs. `subscribe()`?

Comment: Did you read this comment?
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44714124/rxjava-2-0-what-is-the-difference-between-observable-subscribe-and-observable-su#comment79465285_44716163

Comment: If you don't write an operator, you don't have to worry about `subscribeActual()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I may have figured it out. Please comment: 
When you write a custom Observable, you do it by extending the base class. But you want users to be able to `subscribe()`in the normal way. So the base class just forwards the call to your `subscribeActual()` method that does the actual work of subscribing.